# Scatter plots with two values per one name

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am new to scatter plot graphs and can't really figure out how to plots a graph with information that I have. I have several street names (Street 1, Street 2, etc) and each street has two values: average people(Street 1 - 283, street 2 - 894) and average cars(street 1 - 752, street 2 - 26). I am not sure how to choose x and y axis and used 2 values per one name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd

d = {'street': ['Street 1' , 'Street 2'], 'people': [283, 894], 'avg_car': [752, 26]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

colors = ['r', 'g']

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(data={'street': [row['street']], 'people': [row['people']], 'avg_car': [row['avg_car']]})
    plt.scatter(df_tmp.people, df_tmp.avg_car, s=120, c=colors[i], label=str(df_tmp.street))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]